# Flask - 405, Method not allowed

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to send this simple form data to MySQL database using POST method. but same error "Method not allowed", I don't know what's wrong with that. Please help me out here.

HTML Codes:

```
<form role="form" action='/updateabbprof' method="POST">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">About Us</label>
            <textarea class="form-control"  name="updabt" id="editabt"></textarea>
          </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="aupdate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Flask:

```
app.route('/updateabbprof', methods = ['POST'])
def updateaprof():
        try:

                if session.get('user'):
                    _userid = session.get('user')
                    _userabt = str(request.form['updabt'])


                    #if _userid or _username or _email or _phone:
                    con = mysql.connect()
                    cursor = con.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("""UPDATE user_signpp SET user_abt = %s WHERE Id =%s""",(_userabt,_userid))
                    con.commit()
                    cursor.close()
                    con.close()
                    con = mysql.connect()
                    cursor = con.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM user_signpp WHERE Id = %s""",(_userid))
                    con.commit()
                    datanew = cursor.fetchall()
                    session['msg'] = list(datanew[0])
                    cursor.close()
                    con.close()
                    return redirect("/userprofile")
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
        except Exception as e:
                return render_template('error.html', error = str(e))
```

Userprofile route:

```
@app.route('/userprofile', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def userprofile():
        try:
            if session.get('user'):

                        return render_template('profile.html', msg = session.get('msg'))
            else:
                        return redirect('/')
        except Exception as e:
            return render_template('error.html', error = str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the methods that are accepted by `/userprofile`. Probably this view function is set up to accept post requests only?

The redirect from `updateaprof()` will cause the browser to issue a `GET` request to the new location `/userprofile`, which if it doesn't accept GET requests, will return the 405 Method Not Allowed that you are seeing.

If this is the problem you can solve it by adding `GET` to the supported methods and handling the GET request in your view.

It's also possible that `/` has a similar problem, although it's unusual to not support GET requests on the "index" URL.

Comment: check the method userprofle() above, is there anything wrong?

Comment: @LOKESHTIWARI: mmm, probably not. Did you also check `/`? Also, the `SELECT` query in `updateaprof()` looks wrong - you should be passing a tuple to `execute()`. This code should cause an exception so the redirect to `/userprofile` probably isn't happening, and perhaps the problem really is on `/`? Finally you don't need to close the cursor and connection between the queries, nor do you need to commit after a `SELECT`.

Comment: after restarting the server I wrote the codes again.. and now its working.. . also I removed the cursor,connection and commit b/w the queries. thanx for helping me :)